# How to resolve heroku request timeout error

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, webrtc

On deploying the node js application on Heroku, I am getting a request timeout error and I don't know any way to resolve this because there is no way to detect which request is taking more than 30 sec (as far as I know) to complete.

As the application is a simple webrtc video call app, I am sending just an offer and answer to the signaling server so, there is no database involvement here and also there is no need for uploading any files to the server.

I am very confused about which method is taking longer than 30 sec, I have no idea that how to debug it. so, if you any way to debug it or to solve this issue please help me.

**Heroku logs**

```
2021-05-18T06:44:52.612098+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on port 3000...
2021-05-18T06:44:54.026643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-18T06:45:25.592360+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-30775.herokuapp.com request_id=7f7f97cb-a18c-4e0b-afbd-fd360750e820 fwd="223.233.121.52" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-05-18T06:45:44.620505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-30775.herokuapp.com request_id=b5381208-43bb-482f-a52e-944caceeac4e fwd="223.233.121.52" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-05-18T06:46:19.170997+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-spire-30775.herokuapp.com request_id=832319e9-5d66-4c35-8be1-78e6ed8cd8e0 fwd="223.233.121.52" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-05-18T06:46:50.490093+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-spire-30775.herokuapp.com request_id=863c9f21-5920-4493-bee5-9f88dae78bd3 fwd="223.233.121.52" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) onto your heroku app which gives insight into some details about which requests are taking time to complete. [Add New Relic to Heroku app.](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/newrelic)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
2021-05-18T06:44:52.612098+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on port 3000...
```

Your application listens on port 3000 (default NodeJS) and this cannot work on Heroku: you need to bind to the port assigned by Heroku, which you can find in the env variable `$PORT`.
See the [Heroku Nodejs documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs)

Comment: Do you have a different problem? Or you solved the original problem and it is all working now?